# Как правильно подключить MySQL к Си?

Tags: mysql, c, база-данных

Не могу понять как нужно подключать MySQL к Си. 
Некоторые пишут, что это нужно делать через Connecter MySQL C, также говорят, что нужно указывать путь к заголовочному файлу... 
Мб вы поясните более подробно как именно это нужно делать...

Буду благодарен

Comment: Наверное, в вопросе стоит упомянуть еще любимый компилятор и платформу, т.к. от этого многое зависит. В частности, собранные для одних версий VS (бинарные, которые раздают на оф. сайте) коннекторы почему-то несовместимы с другими версиями студии...

Comment: Здравствуйте, я использую Dev C++. Совсем все плохо с подключением.... компилятор MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, подключать действительно надо через Connector. И заголовочные файлы - нужны. И пути к заголовочным файлам при сборке компилятору - надо. И пути к библиотеке (если библиотека не в стандартном месте для компилятора) - тоже указать надо.

Но вот использовать ли MySQL Connector, изначально заточенный под косяки Visual Studio - это еще большой вопрос. У меня с первого раза с MingW оно не завелось. Но есть еще MariaDB (форк MySQL) и его коннекторы вполне неплохо могут работать как с родной MariaDB, так и с MySQL. Но тут тоже не все гладко :-). Бинарники (библиотеки) тоже собраны под VS. Но можно стащить исходники и собрать со своим компилятором. Я взял отсюда: https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/client-native-2.0.0/src/mariadb_client-2.0.0-src.tar.gz/from/http%3A//ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.mariadb.org/?serve коннектор версии 2.0.0 (почему-то 2.1.0 не завелся :-( - может я чего не так просил?..), установил себе CMake, сконфигурировал и сгенерил мейкфайлы, а затем просто командой make (в каталоге коннектора/клиента) собрал библиотеки. С mingw-w64 gcc 7.2 (сейчас перепроверил) этот коннектор нормально собрался. Далее, сгенерированную библиотеку (там есть и статическая, и динамическая) подложил к проекту - и все заработало.

Makefile для сборки с библиотекой коннектора можно примерно такой (да он и не нужен для маленького примера, но раз валялся...):

```
CC = gcc
INCLUDES = -I e:\cpp\mysql\mariadb_client-2.0.0-src\include
LIBS = -L e:\cpp\mysql\mariadb_client-2.0.0-src\libmariadb -llibmariadb.dll
#LIBS = -L e:\cpp\mysql\mariadb_client-2.0.0-src\libmariadb -lmariadbclient # статическая библиотека

all: mysql_query
mysql_query.o: mysql_query.c
      $(CC) -c $(INCLUDES) mysql_query.c
mysql_query: mysql_query.o
      $(CC) -o mysql_query mysql_query.o $(LIBS) 
clean:
      rm -f mysql_query mysql_query.o
```

Естественное, пример программы я брал тоже из стандартных примеров или из книжки.

И на всякий случай привожу тестовую программу - файл `mysql_query.c`:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <errmsg.h>
#include <mysqld_error.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Дескриптор соединения
  MYSQL conn;

  // Получаем дескриптор соединения
  if(!mysql_init(&conn))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't create MySQL-descriptor\n");
    exit(1);
  } 
  // Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
  if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,
                         "localhost",
                         "root",
                         "",
                         "shop",
                         0,
                         NULL,
                         0))
  {
    // Если соединение не установлено выводим сообщение об ошибке
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", mysql_error(&conn));
    exit(1);
  }
  // Устанавливаем кодировку соединения, чтобы предотвратить
  // искажения русского текста
  if(mysql_query(&conn, "SET NAMES 'cp1251'") != 0)
  {
    // Если кодировку установить невозможно - выводим сообщение об ошибке
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't set character set\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  // Добавляем новый раздел - "Накопители"
  if(mysql_query(&conn, "INSERT INTO catalogs VALUES (NULL,'Накопители')") != 0)
  {
    // Если добавить запись не получилось - выводим сообщение об ошибке
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't execute INSERT-query\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  // Закрываем соединение с сервером базы данных
  mysql_close(&conn);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Vladimir, но мне кажется я просто не осилю данное действие. Не могли бы вы пояснить как как правильно подключить MySQL уже к Visual Studio или подсказать ресурсы откуда можно взять информацию. Просто находил только инструкции по подключению к C++.  
Буду крайне благодарен за оказанную помощь .

Comment: С Visual Studio ситуация странная. Ну, т.е. в чем-то с ним проще, в чем-то сложнее. Проще, поскольку и MariaDB и MySQL коннекторы собирают именно под VS. Можно взять VS 2013 или 2015 (насколько я понял. Стащить последний коннектор от MySQL (вот здесь: https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32.zip). Или где-то рядом, если хотите в виде инсталлера. После установки всего этого добра надо только добавить в проект пути к заголовочным файлам и библиотекам и сами библиотеки. Там есть 2 разных варианта для vs12 и vs14 (2013 и 2015, как я понимаю, не перепутайте).

Comment: А сложность в том, что Microsoft очень не любит язык Си и, соответственно, не поддерживает даже стандарт 99 года. Возникает вопрос: зачем в таких условиях использовать коннектор на Си, если VS больше любит C++?.. Более того, раз в языке никаких изменений нет... Зачем понадобилось 2 разных варианта сборок для VS12 и VS14? Формат бинарных файлов поменяли?.. Ну и самое неприятное, что Вас вынуждают работать именно с этими версиями VS. Если захотите другие - тогда снова пляски с  бубном, попытка пересборки (как правило, неудачная, ибо там заточено под версию на уровне кода, проверял на VS2010).

Comment: Vladimir, большое спасибо вам.